# Phonegap JQM fixed header and footer moves/ hides after dismissing android Keyboard

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, header, footer, cordova-2.0.0

I have created a page in which I'm using 4 collapsible. the problem is when I run the app in the emulator or mobile and Input something in the text field after dismissing the keyboard some time the header and footer hides and some time it slides along with the page and after taping on the page it again appears.I am using jQM1.3.1.js files. can anyone tell what is the issue and how can I solve it.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can avoid the header and footer toggle on tap using the following in your header tag.

**data-tap-toggle="false"**

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="o">
```

Also in case your header or footer jumps at stick somewhere not at the top of the page. Try this:

This was reported as a jQM bug but still is not fixed.
I am using jQM 1.3.2 and it is still there, when you are scrolling down the bottom of the page and click on a text field or input the keyboard appears and all is ok, and once the element lost focus the header jumps and fixed itself not at the top of the page.

Try this solution which works for me, taken from the thread noted below.

```
// Workaround for buggy header/footer fixed position when virtual keyboard is on/off
$('input, textarea')
.on('focus', function (e) {
    $('header, footer').css('position', 'absolute');
})
.on('blur', function (e) {
    $('header, footer').css('position', 'fixed');
    //force page redraw to fix incorrectly positioned fixed elements
    setTimeout( function() {
        window.scrollTo( $.mobile.window.scrollLeft(), $.mobile.window.scrollTop() );
    }, 20 );
});
```

Other solutions are posted here. It is a worth looking thread:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5532

Comment: sorry, where do you paste this piece of code? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this android nasty is to use the inputs focus and blur events.

In jQuery: if you are using html5 footer tag or change to class name if necessary.

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $('footer').hide();
});

$("input").blur(function(){
    $('footer').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use these settings after jQuery js file and before jQuery mobile js file:
<script>     
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {

  $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.tapToggle = false;
  $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.hideDuringFocus ="";

});
</script>
```

Comment: can you give an example of this when I wrote <script>tag after jquery.js file and before JQM.js file its showing invalid text string

Comment: hope you are setting it to the mobileinit event.